# Increasing Linux DMA_ZONE memory on ARM i.MX287

Tags: c, linux, arm, virtual-memory, dma

I am working in an Embedded Linux system which has the 2.6.35.3 kernel.

Within the device we require a 4MB+192kB contiguous DMA capable buffer for one of our data capture drivers. The driver uses SPI transfers to copy data into this buffer.

The user space application issues a mmap system call to map the buffer into user space and after that, it directly reads the available data.

The buffer is allocated using "alloc_bootmem_low_pages" call, because it is not possible to allocate more than 4 MB buffer using other methods, such as kmalloc.

However, due to a recent upgrade, we need to increase the buffer space to 22MB+192kB. As I've read, the Linux kernel has only 16MB of DMA capable memory. Therefore, theoretically this is not possible unless there is a way to tweak this setting.

If there is anyone who knows how to perform this, please let me know?

Is this a good idea or will this make the system unstable?

Answer (score 3):

The `ZONE_DMA` 16MB limit is imposed by a hardware limitation of certain devices.  Specifically, on the PC architecture in the olden days, [ISA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Industry_Standard_Architecture) cards performing DMA needed buffers allocated in the first 16MB of the physical address space because the ISA interface had 24 physical address lines which were only capable of addressing the first 2^24=16MB of physical memory.  Therefore, device drivers for these cards would allocate DMA buffers in the `ZONE_DMA` area to accommodate this hardware limitation.

Depending on your embedded system and device hardware, your device either is or isn't subject to this limitation.  If it is subject to this limitation, there is no software fix you can apply to allow your device to address a 22MB block of memory, and if you modify the kernel to extend the DMA address space beyond 16MB, then *of course* the system will become unstable.

On the other hand, if your device is not subject to this limitation (which is the only way it could possibly write to a 22MB buffer), then there is no reason to allocate memory in `ZONE_DMA`.  In this case, I think if you simply replace your `alloc_bootmem_low_pages` call with an `alloc_bootmem_pages` call, it should work fine to allocate your 22MB buffer.  If the system becomes unstable, then it's probably because your device *is* subject to a hardware limitation, and you *cannot* use a 22MB buffer.

Comment: Ideally alloc_bootmem_pages should allocate memory from ZONE_NORMAL as per [link](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand008.html). However, in my case when I do just that, I get a Kernel panic during the startup and when I analyzed the dump, I could see that the panic is triggered by a dma_alloc_coherent call. If alloc_bootmem_pages is allocating memory from ZONE_NORMAL how can a Kernel panic of this sort come? I guess this should be a separate question.

Comment: I assume that your driver is not calling `dma_alloc_coherent` directly.  What is the error message in the kernel panic, and does the backtrace show that `dma_alloc_coherent` was called from within your driver (and within the `alloc_bootmem_pages` call in particular)?  Also, what embedded architecture is this?

Comment: It's not my driver, what causes the Kernel panic is some Ethernet driver calling dma_alloc_coherent. It's like, since I have allocated all the memory, some other driver in the system cannot allocate it's required DMA buffer. Kernel panic says, out of memory. My architecture is ARM iMX287.

Comment: How much main memory do you have on this board?  If it's very tight (e.g., 32M or something), then the `alloc_bootmem_pages` may be failing to allocate the 22M buffer above the 16M mark -- if this happens, it falls back on an unconstrained allocation and could suck up all the low memory pages.

Comment: In my case I have 128M memory. I don't think allocation is failing during the `alloc_bootmem_pages` call. I think it allocates all the DMA memory for my buffer and because of that it fails to allocate memory for other modules in the system.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like my first attempt at an answer was a little too generic.  I think that for the specific i.MX287 architecture you mention in the comments, the DMA zone size *is* configurable through the `CONFIG_DMA_ZONE_SIZE` parameter which can be made as large as 32Megs.  The relevant configuration option should be under "System Type -> Freescale i.MXS implementations -> DMA memory zone size".

On this architecture, it's seems safe to modify it, as it looks like it's not addressing a hardware limitation (the way it was on x86 architectures) but just determining how to lay out memory.

If you try setting it to 32Meg and testing both `alloc_bootmem_pages` and `alloc_bootmem_low_pages` in your own driver, perhaps one of those will work.

Otherwise, I think I'm out of ideas.